# How to reduce the length of the border bottom line in css

Tags: css

I am new to front end development. please find the attached images.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

First image : When you compare between 2 values one horizontal line is there, but it is 3/4th of the length.

second image : I have full line, which css property I ned to changes to get 3/4th line?

Comment: I cannot see any line that is 3/4 of any lenght. Maybe I'm missing something, but I only see a small margin on the lef, but that's not a 1/4 of the lenght.

Comment: Yes, the gap is extreme left I was talking about. my bad, its not 3/4th.

Comment: you want to display border bottom only 3/4 , right?

Comment: not 3/4th. I want to have that gap in left side of the border bottom.

Comment: give padding-left to parent element,

Comment: You'll need an element with that length. AFAIK you cannot put a border with different lenght than the element size. The `padding-left` proposed by @NagaSaiA is an option, just try to get an elment with the desired size with a normal border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an element with that length. AFAIK you cannot put a border with different lenght than the element size. Here I'm using the `div` inside the `li` to do the trick because the way the `<li>` tag works. It's rendered with a "gap" (usually called margin or padding) between the bullet and the content. So because the `<div>` is inside the `<li>`, its width is already smaller than the width of `<li>`.

```css
li > div {
  border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><div>Foo 1</div></li>
<li><div>Foo 2</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you provide the code link either codepen or plunker etc.

Comment: @kkom is there any reason you can't copy-paste yourself to codepen or plunker etc?

Comment: Here, which property is getting that gap between Foo 1 and the circle(unordered list).

Comment: @kkom Is not a property, it's the way the `<li>` tag works. It's rendered with a "gap" (usually called margin or padding) between the bullet and the content. So because the `<div>` is inside the `<li>`, its width is already smaller than the width of `<li>`.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option using padding-left to achieve gap at left hand side

```css
.parent{
  padding-left:20px;
}
.child{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:yellow;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="child"></li>
  <li class="child"></li>
</ul>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GdRLOx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but you can simulate a border with a width of 75% using a linear gradient.

```css
.box{
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black 75%, transparent 75%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```